# DateTime returns wrong year

Tags: php, datetime

My code is like following:

```
<?php
$newDate = new DateTime('2012');
echo $newDate->format('Y');
```

Why `$newDate->format('Y')` returns 2015 (current year) and not 2012?

Comment: How is DateTime supposed to understand that a number 2012 is a year? Just throwing arbitrary values into the DateTime constructor won't achieve much.... consider using [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to tell DateTime that the value you're passing is a year - [demo](https://3v4l.org/DUXVM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `2012` is not a valid date string. By default the date and time set into the object will be the current, which is 2015. You can hint what format you are going to use with `DateTime::createFromFormat`

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y', '2012');
echo $date->format('Y');
```